# Express.JS app is conflicting with mysql server

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu, express, pm2

I'm having a bad day trying to find the reason why this bug is occurring to me.

when I run the `express.js app (using pm2)` it makes `MySQL 5.7` server stop and when I try to restart the `MySQL` server it outputs an error.
Bear in mind that the `express.js app` is running on port `80` and `MySQL` is running on port `3306`. and that the `express.js` app is not trying to talk or connect to MySQL in any ways so they shouldn't interact with each other.

> Platform: Digital Ocean, OS: Ubuntu 16.04, Node Version: 8.2.1, MySQL
>   Version: 5.7

```
`journalctl -xe` output :
```

> -- Defined-By: systemd
>   -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>   -- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up. Aug 07 19:37:35 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited,
>   code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Aug 07 19:37:49 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01
>   sshd[20843]: Invalid user db2fenc1 from xxxxxx Aug 07 19:37:49
>   ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 sshd[20843]: input_userauth_request: invalid user
>   db2fenc1 [preauth] Aug 07 19:37:49 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 sshd[20843]:
>   pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Aug 07 19:37:49
>   ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 sshd[20843]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication
>   failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxxx. Aug 07
>   19:37:51 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 sshd[20843]: Failed password for invalid
>   user db2fenc1 from xxxxxx port 60654 ssh2 Aug 07 19:37:51
>   ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 sshd[20843]: Received disconnect from xxxxx port
>   60654:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preau Aug 07
>   19:37:51 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 sshd[20843]: Disconnected from xxxxx
>   port 60654 [preauth] Aug 07 19:38:05 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]:
>   Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
>   -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>   -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>   -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
>   -- The result is failed. Aug 07 19:38:05 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state. Aug 07 19:38:05
>   ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result
>   'exit-code'. Aug 07 19:38:05 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]:
>   mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart. Aug 07
>   19:38:05 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community
>   Server.
>   -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>   -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>   -- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down. Aug 07 19:38:05 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
>   -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>   -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>   -- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up. Aug 07 19:38:05 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited,
>   code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: It would be helpful to see any initialization code in your express app that has to do with mysql, there might be something you're doing on start up that kills mysql.

Comment: as I stated, the express app doesn't have anything to do with MySQL it's based on MongoDB. the only apps that talk to MySQL are WHMCS and phpmyadmin. @jakerella

Comment: Checkout your application's settings or configurations it try to make a connection to MySQL and the authentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the logs from mysql logs? if it's using the default settings, it will be in `/var/log/mysq/`